# Issue with Twitter Bootstrap pills

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I've a problem with Bootstrap tabs/pills plugin.

I'd like to show all `div` (`a`, `b` and `c`), so i don't need tabs to hide them. I'd like to have pills to let the user move from one section to another on the page. The problem:

- When user click the link, content is not shown (example for container `a` and `b`).
- Removing `data-toggle="pill"` content is shown but link is not marked with `.active` class.

I prepared this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLRmp/ to show you the problem. Hope that you can help me, documentation seems a bit poor about pills:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#a">a</a></li>
    <li class=""><a data-toggle="pill" href="#b">b</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#c">c</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="a">I'm not working: when user clicks the link nothing happens.
    But at least link is marked as active!</div>

<div id="b">Me too. I'm not working: when user clicks the link nothing happens. 
    But at least link is marked as active! </div>

<div id="c">I'm working, but link is not marked as active!</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I use  this javascript snippet (loaded on document ready to be applied for all pills)

```
$('ul.nav.nav-pills li a').click(function() {           
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1:** When you click on `href="#c"`, there's no active class added. In your fiddle and code posted on this page, you did not add the `data-toggle="pill"` attribute to the `c` link.

---

**Issue 2:** When inspecting the [boostrap tab javascript file](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js), note the following code at the bottom of their plugin:

```
     /* TAB DATA-API
  * ============ */

  $(function () {
    $('body').on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })
  })
```

Note especially the use of `e.preventDefault()`. I believe this is why your "pill" links are not jumping to the in-page content.

---

**Possible solution:** I suppose there are other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, but one option would be to play with the `.active` class by using your own jquery function.

http://jsfiddle.net/3aANQ/3/

```
$(".nav-stacked li").click(function() {
    $(".nav-stacked li").removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active");
});​
```